# Reprojecting layer with missing prj file using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, error-999999

I have a point shapefile of farms in an area, but the prj file is missing. I know where they are supposed to be but I can't overlay them with existing shapefiles from that area.

I tried to define the projection to WGS84 and then project it to WGS84 UTM Zone33S because it falls in that zone but it gives an error.

I tried that in ArcMap and this error was generated:

> 999999 : Something unexpected caused the tool to fail. Contact Esri Technical Support (http://esriurl.com/support) to Report a Bug, and refer to the error help for potential solutions or workarounds.
> ArcGIS 10.8 Locate topic
> Description
> This is a generic error for which the cause does not have a specific error ID.

> Solution
> For some error cases, additional messages may accompany the 999999 error. Check the log file for accompanying internal system errors that may reveal information about the nature of the error; otherwise, consider contacting Esri Technical Support for assistance.

In QGIS, the reproject tool brought this error for all features in the layer:

> Encountered a transform error when reprojecting feature with id 140.

What should I do?

Comment: It will help to describe when the error occurs and give the error message.

Comment: Please decide whether you wish to ask about ArcMap or QGIS in this particular question.

Comment: You can't just define a layer's projection unless you know the one it was created in, and if you can't do that you can't reproject it.  I suggest you get rid of any prj that you created, and then add the layer to a project with your other shapefiles.  Then keep changing the layer's or the project's coordinate system (or until you get the match you expect.  Then you can define that layer with that coordinate system.  (This assumes your other shapefiles & project have properly defined coordinate systems.)  Then you can reproject the layer, but ArcGIS or QGIS will show it properly "on the fly".

Comment: Where did you get the file from? And where was it created? Also, how are you representing farms using points? If I assume you are using a point to represent a farm(maybe at its center), use the existing file which is falling at the correct place and  calculate the centroids.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. @jonhs I tried your suggestions and it worked after I changed it to various coordinate systems I got an overlay.

Comment: @Yogesh, Thank you; I don't have the boundaries for the farms to calculate their centroids. The coordinates were taken by someone else that just send me the shapefile they created but it didn't have the prj file.